# Does the size of each TCP segment not have to equal the negotiated MSS value

Tags: tcp

I use wireshark and do a test , I see some TCP segments and the negotiated MSS value is 1460.

But I find out that , the size of each TCP segment is 1434 !

I am confused about the result and I have this question: Does the size of  each TCP segment not have to equal the negotiated MSS value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSS indicates the **largest** possible amount of data in the TCP segment. This does not mean that every TCP segment should be of length indicated by MSS. If TCP payload is less, then you will see the value in "Total Length" field in IP header less than MSS.

Comment: I found that each segment is 1434 ,less than MSS, why ?

Comment: MSS does not mean each TCP segment should be of that size. MSS  -> **Maximum** Segment Size

Comment: can you show me the related RFC , I also refer to RFC ,but my english is not very well ,I have not found the point yet

Comment: Look at what TCP options you have enabled.  For example, timestamps will reduce max segment by 12 bytes - 10 for timestamps and 2 for nops padding (in the event there aren't other options to meet the 32-bit boundary requirement).

Comment: MSS  contains neither  the IP header 20 bytes nor TCP header 20 bytes,  so , the options of TCP's header does not matter . No matter the options, when it comes segment, why does the TCP  segment  not reach the whole MSS capacity 1460 which is negotiated

Comment: Prabhu is correct.  If you want to know why, you'll need to provide more information since there are numerous reasons how this could happen.  For example: Are all segments for all conversations capped at 1434?  Are only segments in some conversations reduced to 1434?  Are some segments in some conversations reduced to 1434?  What kind of connection are you testing on (e.g. mobile, corp. lan, home isp, vpn, etc.)?  Are there specific servers you see this on (can you provide an example IP)?  Or, anything else that can describe your scenario.